# How to print out a hashset

Tags: java, hashset

I just now started working with hashsets and I am trying to print it out but all it prints out is its location i tried Iterator and .toString() here is my code :

```
char [] a = RandomWord.toCharArray();
        HashSet<char[]>  set = new HashSet<char[]>();
        set.add(a);
          Iterator<char[]> itr = set.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(" Iterating over HashSet in Java current object: " + itr.next().toString());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to print the content of your array. [`Arrays.toString(char[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) will do that for you :

```
System.out.println(" Iterating over HashSet in Java current object: " + Arrays.toString(itr.next()));
```

Comment: I just printed it out and I am wondering why is is printing out duplicates when it should be removing them?

Comment: @user3097544 Could you add a small example ?

Comment: satellites
 Iterating over HashSet in Java current object: [s, a, t, e, l, l, i, t, e, s]

Comment: That is the only `char` array in your hashset. If you tried adding another char array with `s,a,t,e,l,l,i,t,e,s` it would not be added.

Comment: I mean I wan't it to remove the repeated letters

Comment: So instead of Satellites it would be satelites

Comment: You would want to add each char individually then, and not as an array.

Comment: Note that HashSet is unordered, and may return your objects in seemingly random order.

Comment: @user3097544 Then don't use a Set to achieve that because it will remove the `t`, the `e` and the `s`. So you'll get as output (after reconstructing the String) `sateli`, which is not what you want. What you want to achieve can be done using a regex. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412811/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-string-not-array-without-using-stringbuilder

Comment: So using a Set `Satellites` would be `sateli` and not `satelites`